# efficient way to make different coloured sprites worth different points? (pygame)

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygame

I've been working on an assignment which asks us to create a version of Atari's Break-Out with pygame. Everything's been going pretty smoothly, but I'm stuck on how to make it so that different colours of bricks returns a different amount of points when hit. (eg. red = 1 point, blue = 2 points...)

here's part of the code from the game loop:

```
while keepGoing:
    #collision detection between ball and bricks
    brick_hit = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(ball, brick_group, False)
    if brick_hit:
        ball.change_direction()

    #scorekeeper    
    for hit in brick_hit:
        scorekeeper.point(1)
        hit.kill()
        if scorekeeper.winner() == 1:
            break
```

here's the code for the brick group:

```
#appending brick sprites into a list so its coordinates can be easily manipulated.
bricks = []
x = -35
y = 100
colour = (0, 255, 0)
points = 6
for i in range(108):
    x += 35
    if x == screen.get_width():
        y += 35
        x = 0
        if y == 135:
            colour = (255, 0, 0)
            points = 5
        elif y == 170:
            colour = (0, 0, 255)
            points = 4
        elif y == 205:
            colour = (120, 0, 0)
            points = 3
        elif y == 240:
            colour = (0, 0, 90)
            points = 2
        elif y == 275:
            colour = (0, 0, 200)
            points = 1
    brick = pyBreakoutSprites.Brick(screen, x, y, colour)   
    bricks.append(brick)
```

and here's the Scorekeeper class in a separate module:

```
class Scorekeeper(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, screen):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.__font = pygame.font.SysFont("Helvetica", 20)
        self.__player_score = 0 
        self.__screen = screen

    def point(self, score):
        self.__player_score += score

    def update(self):
        message = "Points: %d" %(self.__player_score)
        self.image = self.__font.render(message, 1, (255, 255, 255))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = (200, self.__screen.get_height()-10)
```

I've tried to use an if statement so that when the brick is a certain colour, the argument in scorekeeper.point(1) changes to another number, but all the bricks still returned one point when hit.

I would appreciate any help I could get. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make the Brick accept a score as part of its init method. then, in the loop, just do `pyBreakoutSprites.Brick(screen, x, y, colour, points)`, and then when you check for collision, you can just do `score += brick.score`.